# calling summary() from within a function does not output anything

Tags: r

Why doesn't this function:

```
test <- function(somebool = FALSE) {

        mydata<-read.csv("mycsvfile.csv")
        if(somebool){
                print("somebool")
                summary(mydata)
        }
        mydata
}

outdata<-test(somebool=TRUE)
print("head")
head(outdata)
```

print the summary within the function call? it does print the "somebool" just before it, but not the summary.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're calling the function `summary` but not printing the result. Just change it to:

```
 print(summary(mydata))
```

Comment: I thought I tried that. Sorry for the trivial question and thanks for the answer.